# How to add a timeout to F.Promise.promise() and/or F.Promise.sequence()

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

This is my code, it's timing out sometimes because google sometimes takes more than 1000ms to return.  I'm probably missing something quite simple, but can't find any decent documentation on how to do this.  Any help much appreciated!

```
    final List<F.Promise<List<Event>>> promises = new ArrayList<F.Promise<List<Event>>>();
    F.Promise<List<Event>> primaryCalendar = F.Promise.promise(() -> getEvents(staff,startDate,endDate,"primary",credential));
    promises.add(primaryCalendar);

    for (ExtraCalendar extraCalendar : staff.extraCalendars) {
        promises.add(F.Promise.promise(() -> getEvents(staff, startDate, endDate, extraCalendar.googleCalendarId, credential)));
    }
    F.Promise<List<List<Event>>> events = F.Promise.sequence(promises);
    return events;
```

The exception I'm getting is :-

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [1000 milliseconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219) [scala-library-2.11.2.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223) [scala-library-2.11.2.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:116) ~[scala-library-2.11.2.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread$$anon$3.block(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:169) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3640) [scala-library-2.11.2.jar:na]
```

The getEvents code is here as requested, but I don't think it's relevant (it's not a promise).

```
    public static List<Event> getEvents(Staff staff, Date startDate, Date endDate, String googleCalendarId, Credential credential) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, NotAuthorizedException {
        com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar googleClient;
        googleClient = getGoogleClient(credential);
        try {
            if ( Cache.get(getColorCacheKey(staff)) == null ) {
                Colors colors = googleClient.colors().get().execute();
                Cache.set(getColorCacheKey(staff), colors);
            }
            Events events = null;
            DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate);
            DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate);
            // Description might be useful, but it could be big..

            events = googleClient.events().list(googleCalendarId).
                    setFields("items(colorId,summary,end,id,location,start,htmlLink),summary,timeZone").
                    setSingleEvents(true).
                    setTimeMin(start).setTimeMax(end).
                    setMaxResults(1000). // Default 250, max 2500
                    setOrderBy("startTime").
                    execute();
            if ( events.getNextPageToken() != null ) { // This means there are more..  Ignoring for now?
                Logger.warn("events.getNextPageToken() = " + events.getNextPageToken());
            }
            return events.getItems();
        } catch (TokenResponseException | GoogleJsonResponseException e) { // Can happen because they de-authorised?  Or haven't used the site in ages?
            // TODO : Check the exception to see if I can confirm it's really an authError.
            throw new NotAuthorizedException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the `getEvents` code?

Comment: It's now above Salem.  I don't THINK it's relevant though, as it's not a promise itself (just wrapped in one in the calling method).  I really just want to know how to set the timeout on the promise.  F.Promise.promise() and F.Promise.timeout() are both static calls returning a Promise, so I don't see how to mix them?

Comment: On further reflection, I suppose my question can be simplified to how do I set a timeout on a controller method that returns a Promise, yet another place where the Java documentation seems inferior to the Scala docs..  The [Scala docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAsync) show how to do it, but the [Java ones](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync) don't.  How do I do Future.firstCompleted in Java?  And why, oh why does the java docs suck so much :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Megazord on the play google group for an answer.  Note, this isn't in the Java docs mentioned in the above comment, but something similar is in the Scala docs.

---

Since Play uses Akka, you could use it too (btw, most of the time you need to use futures and actors, you will be more well served by Akka docs). Here is an simple example of how to do that in Java:

```
import play.libs.Akka;
import akka.dispatch.Futures;
import akka.dispatch.MessageDispatcher;
import scala.concurrent.Future;
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext;

Future<User> future1 = null;
Future<User> future2 = null;
Future<User> future3 = null;
List<Future<User>> futures = Arrays.asList(future1, future2, future3);

ExecutionContext executor = Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("your-dispacher-name");
// Or to get the default dispacher
// ExecutionContext executor = Akka.system().dispatcher();

Futures.firstCompletedOf(futures, executor).map( ... );
```